# How to find element by text?

Tags: javascript, cypress

If in website there is the design now button or h1 tag is found, still goes to the else part.

Html code

```
<main>
  <h1>Return dynamic status code</h1>
  <p>"Off-the-shelf products" are not your thing. Then just design your own.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/steps">Design Now</a>
</main>
```

My code

```
// By design now button
    cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        if (body.find('.btn-secondary').contains('Design Now').length > 0) {
            cy.log('Return dynamic status code')
        } else {
            cy.log('remove products')
            s2.productlist().find('.close-img').then(($ele) => {
                cy.get($ele).click({ multiple: true, force: true })
            })
        }
    })

    // by h1 text
    cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        if (body.find('h1').text('Return dynamic status code').length > 0) {
            cy.log('Return dynamic status code')
        } else {
            cy.log('remove products')
            s2.productlist().find('.close-img').then(($ele) => {
                cy.get($ele).click({ multiple: true, force: true })
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: I'd guess that the page is not ready yet. Maybe swap `body` to `main`?

Comment: main is already in body so it doesn't matter

Comment: This `body.find('.btn-secondary').contains('Design Now')` is invalid syntax, but this `body.find('h1').text('Return dynamic status code')` will work, so the only explanation is the `<h1>` has not appeared yet.

Comment: If you add `cy.contains('h1', 'Return dynamic status code')` before the 2nd section, it should work.